# Saving skspritenode position to plist doesn't work

Tags: ios, plist, skspritenode, writetofile

What I'm doing is simple, I'm trying to save a sprite node coordinate to a plist.  It works fine if I force in a static value by hand, but if I try and take the **node.position.x** into the plist it doesn't work.  I of course place the node.position.x into an NSNumber before using writeToFile.

One other note is that I'm calling this function from the: - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application

function of appdelegate.

Looking at the console all the node positions show up fine, they just don't get written to the plist.  I'm seriously at a loss, again, if I force a number in there like 6 or 10 or something it writes fine.

Any assistance would be GREATLY appreciated.

```
for (SKSpriteNode* node in ar){
            NSNumber* x = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)node.position.x];
            NSNumber* y = [NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)node.position.y];
            [node_locs addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:x,@"X",y,@"Y",nil]];
        }
```

Then I do the usual writeToFile which I know works.

Comment: If you believe the problem is that the application doesn't have enough time to write the content to disk, try to create a [background task](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/) that will handle it.

Comment: I just discovered the applicationWillResignActive method is called twice and the second time the node position is overwritten with an old x and y position.  I seem to have the issue of my viewDidLoad method being called more than once from the view controller for my skscene and for that matter the skscene didMoveToView method is called multiple times as well.  What could be causing this?

Comment: To be honest I'm not even sure how the load methods are related to the resigning delegate method, but normally `viewDidLoad` can be called twice at about the same time if you present two view different controllers with the same configuration. Try to debug it and compare the view controllers at these two calls.

Comment: I appreciate the input. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so that was my problem.  My method for saving the coordinates was called twice when I called my **NSNotificationCenter** method.  I don't know why it does this, but it's very annoying.  If fixed my problem at this point. Thanks for the response man.